# Rails Validation Using Format and Regex

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

What is the correct method of validating an input string such that it can only contain 0-9, a-z and '.'? The first and last character must not be a '.'.

I'm currently using;

```
validates_format_of :lagrange, :with => /[0-9a-z\.]/
```

and have tried many variants but can't seem to figure this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use zero width assertion lookahead

```
/^(?!.*[.]$)(?![.])[a-z0-9.]+$/
  ---------
```

`+` is a quantifier to match 1 to many times

`^` marks the beginnig and `$` marks the end of string/line..

Comment: Great! Your solution works. And you answered it so quickly that I am not yet able to mark it as a solution!
I'll go and read up on zero width assertion look ahead and come right back.

Comment: To account my my question edit about the first and last character not being a '.', would I do this?  `/^[^.](?!.*[.]$)[a-z0-9.]+$/`

Comment: @ObregonCornsnook don't use `[^.]`..that means match anything except `.`

Comment: -1 for unnecessary lookaround and use of `[.]`, Also `^$` match beginning and end of line. Many problems with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Word boundaries are your friend:

```
/\A\b[a-z\d.]*\b\z/
```

See why?